# how to display object data in react with map method

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-hooks

`const [data, setData] = useState({dataOne: "", dataTwo: ""});`

How can i render both object values in **One** react table?

Here's Json Response

dataOne

```
[{
    "name": "adnan hassan",
    "count": 6960
}, {
    "name": "adnan",
    "count": 69666660
}]
```

dataTwo

```
[{
    "metrics": {
        "competition": "LOW",
        "avg_searches": "6600",
        "competition_index": "22"
    },
    "keyword_annotations": {
        "concepts": []
    },
    "text": "dubai homes"
}]
```

i want to show Count from **dataOne** & avg_searches, text from **dataTwo** in table.
Map method Working one by one Like this `data.dataOne.map()` & `data.dataTwo.map()`  But i want to render both values in one method like `data.map()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the two arrays: using:

```
mergedArray = [...arr1, ...arr2]
```

```js
dataOne = [{
    "name": "adnan hassan",
    "count": 6960
}, {
    "name": "adnan",
    "count": 69666660
}]

dataTwo = [{
    "metrics": {
        "competition": "LOW",
        "avg_searches": "6600",
        "competition_index": "22"
    },
    "keyword_annotations": {
        "concepts": []
    },
    "text": "dubai homes"
}]

let merged = [...dataOne, ...dataTwo]
console.log(merged)

// Then after you can map the data based on what you want
console.log('--mapped data starts here--')
merged.map((val) => {
  console.log(val)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Cypherjac for your direction. i solved this problam with https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mergeWith

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).